# radio button list not checked properly when using timer on same page

Tags: asp.net

i m using radio button list, but not checked properly when using timer on same page going unchecked automatically , if two are three times click on radio button list then selected.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel  ID="UpdPanel"  runat="server" >
     <Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1"
    EventName="tick" />
</Triggers>
      <ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry, cannot understand the question. Can you rephrase clearer?

Comment: i m using radio button list if i am going to select option click on radiobuttonlist but automatically radiobuttonlist unchecked i m using timer on same page